# Source Column not properly being identified on CSV file import in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, csv, workbench, csv-import

### Scenario

Working on "Google Sheets" for quite some time now, I am working to migrate my data over to `MySQL` Database. I've downloaded the sheet from Google Sheets as a `CSV` file and trying to import into Workbench MySQL table. An issue I'm running into is the format of these columns during the data import. It appears Workbench isn't reading my column headers properly and I am unable to map these columns properly to continue my import.

In Workbench, I already created the respective table (users) with proper headers. On the import, I selected to "Use Existing Table" and selected the table created (users). Next, on the window to Configure Import Settings -> Step to map Source Column to a Dest Column, the headers are not coming in properly.

### Resources

[image: This is what it looks like on the Table Data Import Wizard]

[image: Screenshot of my CSV file]

I am on a Macbook. I am using `VSCode` for the text editor for the CSV file. Any tips?

Appreciate your time!

Comment: Sorry i delete my last comment because i made a mistake not reading you using workbench... if you click on more options icon after "Detect File Format: csv" you will see another options.., did you try adjusting those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clic on the wrench icon after "Detected file format" so you will see another options, you must change "field separator" that the default option is semicolon ( ; ) and select comma. you can adjust another settings so your file will read better:

[image]

Comment: Wow completely looked past that. You are the man. I changed the "Field Separator" to (,) and that did the fix. Appreciate your help!